# How can I identify a CORS preflight request?

Tags: cors, preflight

A CORS preflight request obviously uses the OPTIONS method and has an Origin header. However, a browser can decide for *any* HTTP request to add an Origin header. Also, OPTIONS may be used for other functionality than CORS. (How) Can I identify *exactly* (without false positives or negatives) whether a request is a CORS preflight request?

Comment: Why do you care? Preflight requests are designed to be compatible with regular OPTIONS requests. Just respond to all OPTIONS requests in the same way.

Comment: @Quentin If I were to do that, then I might end up answering with a 403 to an otherwise perfectly valid non-CORS-preflight OPTIONS request based on the fact that the client has (needlessly) added an Origin, which then gets checked against the list of valid origins for CORS requests, resulting in that 403.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check for the [Access-Control-Request-Method](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-request-method-request-header) header. It would not make much sense to send it in a request other than the preflight request.

Answer (score 18):

Check for the existence of these essential information present in a preflight request:

1. The request's HTTP method is `OPTIONS`
2. It has an `Origin` header
3. It has an `Access-Control-Request-Method` header, indicating what's the actual method it's trying to use to consume your service/resource

**Considerations**

In theory you you could be a so clever and manually set those headers and try to make some fake-Preflight request for some reason.

However, your browser would complain with the following sample message:
`Refused to set unsafe header "Origin"` (tested as an XHR request on Chrome)
while other apps, such as Postman will set their own `Origin` as, say `Origin: chrome://extension...`